# SQL Count elements based on newest 150 entries in table

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to change two SQL queries I have right now so that in addition to giving me a result from a table, it only gives me that result based on the newest say 150 entries within the table.

My two queries at the moment are:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `stock`.`replacements.archive`
WHERE `ciref` = '$cihistory'
```

and

```
SELECT `req_model`, COUNT(`req_model`) AS `value_occurrence`
FROM `stock`.`replacements.archive`
GROUP BY `req_model`
ORDER BY `value_occurrence` DESC LIMIT 5
```

Is there a way for me to achieve this?
The id field in the table is used as normal so guessing would use this but im not sure how to achieve it

The aim here is to only do the counting of the variable based on the latest 150 entries in the table, i dont want to count everything in the table.

Anyone has any ideas it would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: 150  occurrence of what?   .. table  stock ...?? and how you define  a new entry  ..  you have an autoincrement id .. or a  row created date .?? . (remember that sql have not a prederined  dedfualt order by ) .. you should add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Apply the 150 "newest" rows LIMIT within a *Derived Table* or a CTE and count in the outer Select

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you mean.

Comment: Edited with: The aim here is to only do the counting of the variable based on the latest 150 entries in the table, i dont want to count everything in the table.
does this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you have an autoincremnt id  the you could select the newest 150 entry as

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM `stock`.`replacements.archive` 
    ORDER BY id limit 150
```

and then perform the query on this subquery as

```
    SELECT `req_model`, COUNT(`req_model`) AS `value_occurrence` 
    FROM (  
        SELECT * 
        FROM `stock`.`replacements.archive` 
        ORDER BY id DESC  limit 150 
    ) t
    GROUP BY `req_model` 
    ORDER BY `value_occurrence`
```

Comment: You mean ORDER BY id DESC?

Comment: Thanks this worked a treat, i spotted the order by id DESC before this comment anyway :)